# How can I make a discord bot take input after a command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and trying to give it a !clear command but I am struggling with making the amount of messages needed to be cleared

```
#The modules
import discord
import random
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
#Prefix
client = Bot('!')
#Events
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == '!nuke':
        if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
            await message.channel.send('How many messages do you want to remove?')
            #this is the part I am struggling with
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're using the `commands` extension (Bot), then you should use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of a static message handler. [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) is the documentation for `wait_for` which is what you need to get an input. Another things I noticed,
`server_permissions` doesn't exist, it's `guild_permissions`

Comment: Can I somehow make wait_for wait for a number and not text?

Comment: yes, just modify `check` so that it only returns True if the content can be an integer.

Comment: when I try to do it it gives me an error AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'lower'
the code I am using is
`A = await client.wait_for('message',check=int)

A = A+3

for i in range(0,A,1):

    await message.delete()`

Comment: `check` has to be a function, not a type. `check=lambda msg:msg.content.isdigit()`. However, this will just accept the next message that the bot receives, so you'll want something like: `check=lambda msg: msg.content.isdigit() and msg.channel == message.channel and msg.author.id == message.author.id`
edit: also you need to access the `content` property of a message for its content, not jsut the message itself.

Comment: What is msg in this code? Do I just replace A with msg?

Comment: `msg` is a local variable passed as a parameter to the anonymous `check` function.

Comment: it gives out NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
I copy pasted code given like this(i will make a bunch of space bars on indents)      
`A = await client.wait_for('message',check=lambda msg: msg.content.isdigit()) 
     msg.channel == message.channel      msg.author.id == message.author.id`

Comment: 1) you're missing `and`, 2) you've closed the `wait_for` before the end of the check, 3) where does it throw that error?

Comment: 1 and 2) oh I just misunderstood the and, 3) it throws it in line 34 which is msg.channel == message.channel
I properly wrote the code which fixed that error, but now at line 35 it throws this:
   (the line: A = A+3)       
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Message' and 'int'

Comment: as I said before, the message's content can be accessed from the `content` property, not by directly referencing the Message object.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a similar command, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/judev1/FBot/blob/master/FBot_Cogs/purge.py)

The process is pretty straight forward:

1. Get the number of messages of delete
2. Add one
3. Use `ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)`, or `message.channel.purge` in your case, and voila!